# extract number using regular expression

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to extract numbers using regular expression

```
df['price'][0]
```

has

```
'[<em class="letter" id="infoJiga">3,402,000</em>]'
```

And I want to extract `3402000`

How can I get this in pandas dataframe?

Comment: Looks like parsing html with regex to me - naughty developer... https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2071828

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Show data, your desired output and what you tried. You also might want to read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However the value is a string, try the below code.

```
#your code    
df['price'][0] returns  '[<em class="letter" id="infoJiga">3,402,000</em>]'

let us say this is x.

y = ''.join(c for c in x.split('>')[1]  if c.isdigit()).strip()
print (y)

output: 3402000
```

Hope it works.

Comment: if this code is working fine, then accept the answer and upvote for others to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest regex assuming nothing about the environment may be `([\d,]*)`. Than you can pandas' [to_numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) function.

Answer (score 0):

Are all your values formatted the same way? If so, you can use a simple regular expression to extract the numeric values then convert them to `int`.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

test_data = ['[<em class="letter" id="infoJiga">3,402,000</em>]','[<em class="letter" id="infoJiga">3,401,000</em>]','[<em class="letter" id="infoJiga">3,400,000</em>]','[<em class="letter" id="infoJiga">2,000</em>]']
df = pd.DataFrame(test_data)
>>> df[0]
0    [<em class="letter" id="infoJiga">3,402,000</em>]
1    [<em class="letter" id="infoJiga">3,401,000</em>]
2    [<em class="letter" id="infoJiga">3,400,000</em>]
3        [<em class="letter" id="infoJiga">2,000</em>]
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Define a method that extracts and returns to integer

```
def get_numeric(data):
    match = re.search('>(.+)<', data)
    if match:
        return int(match.group(1).replace(',',''))    
    return None
```

Apply it to DataFrame

```
df[1] = df[0].apply(get_numeric)
>>> df[1]
0    3402000
1    3401000
2    3400000
3       2000
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Thanks to your help, I fixed my problem:)

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the question as answered :)